# Nested array and tabular spawns a 't' from nowhere. How to remove it?

Tags: tables, arrays

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      text
      & $
      \begin{array}[cc]{ll}
    & 1
      \end{array}
      $
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

compiled with `pdflatex` will create the following table:
[image: output]

How do I remove the 't' between 'text' and '1'?

here my latex version:

> ```
> pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
> kpathsea version 6.3.1
> Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
> There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
> covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
> the Lesser GNU General Public License.
> For more information about these matters, see the file
> named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
> Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
> Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
> Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
> Compiled with xpdf version 4.01
> ```

Comment: What's this optional argument of array, `[cc]`?

Answer (score 3):

The optional argument to `array` should be one among

```
[t]
[b]
[c]
```

(and the last one can be omitted). That is, a ***single*** character between brackets. Now the fix should be obvious.

What happens is that TeX does the comparison

```
\if #1t
```

and if `#1` is `cc` the comparison reads

```
\if cct
```

The two following characters are equal, so `t` becomes part of the “true text” of the conditional, hence pops up in your output.

---

Maybe the LaTeX kernel could check for the optional argument being a single allowed character. However, the code for `array` hasn't changed in significant way from the beginning of time and was written when memory for TeX was very scarce and too many checks could cause running out of memory.